# swap div's position from top div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to swap a div's position from top on and when I click another div then top div can be swap.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap top">
    <input type="text" value="div1" class="textbox " />
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <input type="text" value="div2" class="textbox " />
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <input type="text" value="div3" class="textbox " />
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
(function ($) {
        $(".wrap").on("click", function () {
            if ($(this).index() == 0) {
            } else {
                $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
            }
        });
    }(jQuery));
```

The fact is I don't want to remove the `div` which I click instead want to swap the positions around.

How Can I do this using `jQuery` itself?

Comment: Do you actually need to swap the code mark-up, or just make an element overlay on top of the other?

Comment: removeClass('top') maybe

Comment: Actually I have a one main big Div and 3 another small Div, big div is on top and another three divs on right side, when i clicked on small div then that div swap from big div and big div is showing small and small div is showing big.

Comment: @YogendraPal Can you provide us with a code sample in a codepen, jsfiddle or embedded SO snippet please?

Comment: @Owen Ayres https://jsfiddle.net/4r4gtn6v/

Comment: @Owen Ayres- Currently this code is swapping from parent but i need they swap from top. means when click on **3** then 1 is swap from 3 after that when click on 4 then (currently 3 on the top place then) that is swap from 3 because 3 is on top.

Comment: @YogendraPal so you want whatever clicked one to be pushed to the top of those 4? I.e. if 2 is the bottom div and I click it, it goes directly to the top and the other three divs push down one place?

Comment: when i click on whatever div but they can swap from first top div.

Comment: @YogendraPal so if div 2 is the bottom one and div 4 is at the top, and I click div 2, does that mean div 2 is now at the top and div 4 is at the bottom? I.e. a direct swap?

Comment: @Owen Ayres- Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: @YogendraPal Yes, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using css to position the top `div` and just swap the class as follows:

```
(function ($) {
        $(".wrap").on("click", function () {
            if ($(this).index() == 0) {
            } else {
                $(".wrap").removeClass("top");
                $(this).addClass("top");
            }
        });
    }(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

this will swap whatever you click with the first element.

```
$(".wrap").on("click", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.index() == 0) {
  } else {
    var first = $this.siblings('.wrap').first();
    first.insertBefore($this);
    $this.prependTo($this.parent());
  }
});
```

if you just want to move the clicked element to the top, you can simply do

```
$this.prependTo($this.parent());
```

Answer (score -1):

To swap the two DOM elements using jQuery, you could use something like this: -

```js
 (function($) {
   $(".wrap").on("click", function(event) {
     var index = $(event.target).index();
     var first = $(".wrap").first();

     if (index > 0) {
       $(first).swapWith(this);
     }
   });
 }(jQuery));


 jQuery.fn.swapWith = function(to) {
   return this.each(function() {
     var copy_to = $(to).clone(true);
     var copy_from = $(this).clone(true);
     $(to).replaceWith(copy_from);
     $(this).replaceWith(copy_to);
   });
 };
```

```css
.wrap {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #2d8cd0;
}
h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <h2>1</h2>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <h2>2</h2>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <h2>3</h2>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <h2>4</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: you could do this much simpler.  first.insertBefore($(this));  $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());